# Firebase Analytics doesn't show any data in dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log an event and current screen with Firebase Analytics and I'm getting this logs in my logcat:

```
App measurement is starting up, version: 9877
Registered activity lifecycle callback
Checking service availability
Service available
Connecting to remote service
onActivityCreated
Activity resumed, time: 234385086
Connected to remote service
Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=9309, _sc=IntroActivity, _si=-6959962515326329023}]
setCurrentScreen cannot be called while no activity active
Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=main, _o=app, content_type=image, item_id=1}]
```

and this is my code:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "1");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "main");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(MainActivity.this,"Main","Home");
```

but after going to Firebase console there is no data from my application. why?

Comment: The events don't appear in the Firebase Console for a number of hours.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log) indicates "_These dashboards update periodically throughout the day_".

Comment: qbix's answer is right. Your code seems correct. But I think you should set the current screen _before_ firing the event.

Comment: thanks you're right but I thought it's real time @qbix

Answer (score 9):

As the method documentation mentions you should call [setCurrentScreen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setCurrentScreen(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) from the activity [onResume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) callback while the activity is in foreground (before [onPause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) is callback is called). The screen name/class applies only to the current activity that is foreground. Calling it without activity is foreground is not possible as there is no visible UI to associate the screen name/class with and therefore you get the warning that this call has no effect.